# Resolve left-recursion in XText SQL-grammar defining tables and joins

Tags: antlr, xtext

For practice, I am currently defining the grammar for simple SELECT statements such as

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 JOIN table 2 AS t2 ON (t1.field1=t2.field2);
```

For this, I use XText. Here is an extract of the grammar, defining tables in the FROM part:

```
table: 
    name=ID (('AS')? alias=ID)?
    | 
    join
;

join:
    left_table=table (type=join_type)? 'JOIN' right_table=table 'ON' condition=predicate
;
```

Obviously, the rule "table" is left recursive.
I've read all guides describing how to resolve left-recursion in XText (or ANTLR respectively). But I don't understand it or at least, I can't map the explanations to my particular code...

What is the problem with my definition and how can I resolve the left-recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is going to be a big operation on your grammar.

Why is it left-recursive?

- table : join ; // so join is a left-most non-terminal for table
- join  : table 'JOIN' table 'ON' condition ; // so table is a left-most non-terminal for join
- the mutual recursion and the two uses of join and table being left-most makes both rules left-recursive

How to fix this?

- you could rewrite the JOIN rule as a list: `join: ('JOIN' table)*`
- and whatever you need to change in the rest of the grammar to make this change syntax-preserving.
- note that the change will affect the shape of your tree model

Comment: So how would I need to adjust the rule `table`? If I only adjust `join` like you suggested, `join` and `table` would become superclasses of themselves which is also not allowed.

Comment: *subclasses=super types

Comment: it will take a lot of changes Paddre. Just make sure each rule starts with a terminal somehow.